# Output script that contains undefined variables

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing a Node module that will take in some parameters, and output a client-side script that contains references to DOM APIs like `document`. Right now it looks something like this

```
module.exports = function(a, b){
  return (function(){
            function run(a, b){
               console.log(a + ' and ' + b);
            }

            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', run(a,b);
         }).toString()
}
```

And then I can use it like

```
var myModule = require('./myModule.js')
var fs = require('fs)
fs.writeFile('script.js', myModule("A", "B"), () => .....)
```

This isn't working because `document` isn't defined, but it definitely feels like there's a certain design pattern for this that I haven't thought of.

Is there a better solution for writing a script that outputs another script like this?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Added a more clear question. Is there a better solution for writing a script that outputs another script like this?

Comment: @Weston I guess you want some sort of pre-processing and marcos... have a look at http://sweetjs.org/

Comment: @Weston the reason that's not working has nothing to do with `document` being undefined. Once you stringify the function, the scoping for `a` and `b` becomes broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By enclosing a function into parenthesis, i.e. `(...)`, you are executing this function without parameters. Then you apply `toString()` to the result.
If you want to pass a function as a string, just put it in quotes, like this:

```
module.exports = function(a, b){
  return 'function(){
            function run(a, b){
               console.log(a + ' and ' + b);
            }

            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', run);
         }';
}
```

Comment: I thought about just wrapping the thing in quotes, but figured there has to be a better design since that makes it really hard to test since I'd have to just resort to eval(). But I think I might just be overcomplicating it.

Comment: @Weston how do you expect to execute that function in node.js without eval? No matter where you pass it, `document` _in that scope_ will always be `undefined`.

Comment: Well the real script would likely have some functions that don't touch the DOM at all and can be unit tested in Node. But when the script only exists as the string, that testing would have to be done after another module runs this function and gets a real script, and then somehow, someway interprets it as a module that I can test. Which may actually be a better design, which is partly why I'm asking since this is uncharted territory for me.

Comment: @Weston You have an option other than eval(): Write the script to the file and then load is via <script> tag.